# Strange definition for finitely generated subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

My teacher gave a definition of a finitely generated subspace $[S]$. I don't even know what does this mean and why it's useful to define, but he said that:

Suppose a vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$, and

$$S = \{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$$

(and $S$ is a subset of $V$, not a subspace)

$$[S]=:\cap_{w\subset V, w\supseteq S} W$$

In other words, $[S]$ is, by definition, the intersection of all $W$, such that $W$ is a subset of $V$ and $W$ contains $S$.

He, then, proved that this definition is the equivalente of saying that $[S]$ is the same as the set 
$$W = \{\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_nu_n|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R\}$$

Also, can you show me an example of an $W$ that is a subspace of a vector space $V$ such that the intersection of all the subspaces that contains $S$ is equal to the linear combinations of $S$?

I tried to verify that:

Suppose $S$ is a subset (not subspace) of $\mathbb R^2$, let's consider $S = \{(1,0)\}$. Then if I get all the $W$ such that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W$ must contain at least $(0,0)$, and since $W$ must contain $S$ by definition, let $W = \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$. Why, then, the intersection of all possible $W$'s is the set $\{\lambda(1,0)|\lambda \in \mathbb R\}$?

Also, when it says $S$ contains $u_1, \cdots , u_n$, what are these? Vectors of the vector space?

He said that he prefer this definition because it leads to $[\emptyset] = \{0\}$. Could you help me proving it?

Thank you by all of you guys who take time to answer my questions, I love this forum so much.

Comment: We also call $W$ the subspace of $V$ *spanned* by $S$. Yes, the elements $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ of $S$ are vectors in the vector space $V$, and the linear combinations shown in the "explicit" set description of $W$ are formed using the vector space operations of (real vector space) $V$.

Comment: @hardmath could you complete my example with a bit more vectors and show that their intersection is indeed $\alpha(1,0)$?

Comment: I'm on the road for the moment, so it's a bit too much to handle via my smartphone, but when I get back to the house and keyboard, if no one else has taken up the challenge, I will do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you give should help you to understand how the two approaches agree.

On the one hand you can think of the *span* of a (finite) set $S \subseteq V$ as the *smallest* vector space $W_S = [S]$ containing all of $S$, i.e. the *intersection* of all those *subspaces* $W$ that qualify:

$$ [S] = \bigcap_{S \subseteq W \subseteq V} W $$

For emphasis, this is an intersection over *subspaces* $W$ that contain all of $S$.  Is there such a subspace?  After all, $S$ itself is just a subset of $V$ and not necessarily a subspace.  Indeed, since your $S$ is a finite set, it cannot be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real scalars.  But $V$ is a vector space, and $S \subseteq V$, so yes, there is at least one subspace of $V$ containing $S$ to use in the above intersection, namely $V$ itself, which is certainly a subspace of $V$.

The example you wrote up says at one point $W = \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$, and this is mistaken.  While any subspace $W$ must have the zero element, we cannot take $S \cup \{(0,0)\}$ and call that slightly larger set a subspace.  Vector subspaces must be (a) nonempty and (b) closed under both vector addition and scalar multiplication.  While $S \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is nonempty, it is not closed under either vector addition or scalar multiplication in your example, since $(1,0)+(1,0) = 2*(1,0) \not\in S \cup \{(0,0)\}$.

What we can do is prove that $W = \{\lambda*(1,0)\;\mid\; \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace of $V$, and then argue that $W$ is the smallest such subspace, namely $[S]$.  Note that in your example of $S$ having one element $(1,0)$, $S$ is certainly a finite set and that $W$ corresponds to the set of all linear combinations of vector in $S$ (since $S$ only has one vector in it).

Is $W$ nonempty?  Yes, $S \subseteq W$ by taking $\lambda = 1$, so $W$ is nonempty.

Is $W$ closed under the vector space operations?  First let's handle vector addition.  Suppose I have two elements of $W$ (not necessarily distinct), which we call:

$$ \lambda_1*(1,0), \lambda_2*(1,0) \text{ where } \lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R} $$

Is their sum in $W$?  Because $\lambda_1*(1,0) + \lambda_2*(1,0) = (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)*(1,0)$ according to the vector space properties of $V$, and because:

$$ (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)*(1,0) \in W $$

where $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ by the arithmetic properties of the real numbers, the answer to this part is yes, $W$ is closed under vector addition.

Showing $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication is similar (and easy).  Take a typical element of $W$ and a typical scalar $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and show that scalar multiple of that vector element of $W$ is again an element of $W$.  Thus $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Now that you know this $W$ is a subspace of $V$ that contains $S$, there is one more step.  You need to prove that any subspace $U$ of $V$ that contains $S$ will also contain $W$.  In other words, you have to show $S \subseteq U$ and $U$ a subspace of $V$ implies $W \subseteq V$.

That will complete your example.

Comment: What you mean by "smallest subspace"? Also, what's a "span of a finite set"? I only understood spans for vector spaces and other things.

Comment: Do you know abut any place that uses this definition, where I can study more?

Comment: Here $S$ is a subset of $V$, which is a vector space.  Your notation talks about expressing $[S]$, the subspace of $V$ that is *spanned by* $S$, as both an intersection of all subspaces of $V$ which contain $S$ and more concretely, as the set consisting of all linear combinations of the (finitely many) vectors in $S$.  This is your exercise.  You asked me to help you complete the example you started.  So, are you following your own Question?

Comment: Yes, I think that $[\emptyset]$ is the intersection of all the subspaces that contain $\emptyset$, therefore, the only common elemento in all them is gonna be the $0$ vector? (the zero vector must be contained in all subspaces).

Comment: I guess that's the reason, but every subspace contains the empty set, because every set contains the empty set. So, is it true that the intersection of all the subspaces is the zero vector?

Comment: Yes, the zero subspace $\{0\}$ is spanned by the empty set $S = \emptyset$.  Your example concerned the subspace $W=\{\lambda*(1,0)\;\mid\; \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ spanned by a singleton set $S = \{(1,0)\}$.  More generally we consider finitely generated subspaces $W$ spanned by $S = \{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$.  The dimension of $W$ is then less than or equal to $n$, attaining $n$ only if the vectors in $S$ are linearly independent.