# Let $[S]$ be the span of $S$ by the intersection definition, then $S$ subspace $\implies [S] = S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **My definition of span**:
>
> Suppose a vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$, and
>
> $$S = \{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$$
>
> (and $S$ is a subset of $V$, not a subspace)
>
> $$[S]=:\cap_{w\subset V, w\supseteq S} W$$
>
> In other words, $[S]$ is, by definition, the intersection of all $W$,
>   such that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $W$ contains $S$.

Then suppose I have $S = \{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$ and $S$ is a subspace. Then is it true that

$$[S] = S$$?

What I tried:

If $S$ is a subspace, then because it is closed under addition and multiplication,

$$S = \{\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_nu_n|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R\}$$

Then, I've asked the proof of equivalence between this definition and the usual one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047513/alternative-definition-for-span-and-proving-it-is-equivalent-to-the-most-common). Since they're equivalent:

$$[S] = [\{\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_nu_n|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R\}] =  \{\beta_1(\alpha_1 u_1)+\cdots+\beta_n(a_n u_n)|\alpha_i,\beta_i \in \mathbb R\} = \{(\beta_1\alpha_1)u_1+\cdots+(\beta_n\alpha_n)u_n|\alpha_i,\beta_i\in\mathbb R\} = S$$

I proved that $[S] = S$ because $S = \{\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_nu_n|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R\}$. I think my reasoning is right, could you guys say if I did everything altight? (is my notation right?). Also, could you prove that $[S] = S$ (when $S$ is subspace), by the original definition, without using the equivalence between the first definition and the usual one?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, I wrote subset? Could you point it out?

Comment: Last phrase in highlighted box: "such that $W$ is a SUBSET of $V$".

Comment: @JohnHughes you're right, thanks! I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is a subspace, it can be used as one of the "W"s in the definition of $[S]$, which shows that $[S] \subset S$. But $S \subset [S]$ as well. They're therefore equal, and $[S]$ is a subspace, because it equals $S$, which is a subspace.

Comment: But is my reasoning right?

Comment: No. Your reasoning is pretty confused. First, $\beta$, $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are all undefined, and multiplying a set by a number is undefined, and you haven't even *defined* $[S]$ except for finite subsets of $V$ (because your definition supposes that $S$ consists of the $n$ vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_n$). I ignored that, and gave a proof using the obvious analogous definition for an arbitrary subset $S$ of $V$, thereby answering your last question -- "can this be done without using the equivalence of the two definitions?" --- affirmatively.

Comment: You're right, there's no sense in what I wrote. I meant, that if $S$ is a subspace, then $S$ is equal to all the possible linear combinations of $u_1,\cdots,u_n$. Then, $[S]$ is by the common definition, the set of all possible linear combinations of $S$, therefore, all $\{\beta_1(\alpha_1 u_1)+\cdots+\beta_n(a_n u_n)|\alpha_i,\beta_i \in \mathbb R\}$, which is in $S$  again

Comment: Even this explanation of what you meant is meaningless in the case where $S$ is infinite dimensional, and therefore might not have a finite basis. Consider, for instance, the vector space $V$ consisting of all infinite sequences of real numbers with the property that the infinite sequence is eventually all zeroes. The set of "basic sequences" (ones that are all zero except for a single term that's "1") has the property that every element of $V$ a finite linear combination of the basic sequences. But that set of basic sequences is infinite. Contrast with $W$=all sequences of reals.

Comment: but how to prove $S \subset [S]$ without using the linear combination definition? Can't see that $S$ is contained

Comment: In the defintion of $[S]$, namely,  $[S] = \cap_{W \text{ a subspace of } V, S \subset W} W$, you'll notice that $S$ is a subset of every $W$; it's therefore in the intersection of the $W$s, which is, after all, the elements that are in all of them, which certainly includes all elements of $S$. I'm using a generalization of the idea that if $X \subset A$ and $X \subset B$, then $X \subset A \cap B$.